# Different actionRequest by environment

Tags: java, redirect, request, liferay

I have a different behaviour / different actionRequest in localhost and other environment.

The line in question is:

```
String redirect = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "redirect");
```

In local that actionRequest have the param "Redirect", but in the other environment is NULL.

How can i print or check where or why this request is null?

Comment: How are you passing this from your `jsp` form?

Comment: Is the submit button of deleteContent. In my local works fine, but in other environments, the content is deleted but the red error message of portlet unavailable appears.
Throws the next NPE:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a valid redirect
 at com.liferay.portlet.ActionResponseImpl.sendRedirect(ActionResponseImpl.java:37)

Comment: Please post your addition code from your `jsp/html` form? Are you using `aui ` taglib?

Comment: The Jsp, Is the out of the box funcionality of liferay to delete content. In WebContent administration view, on the corner of each content, open the menu and click on "delete".

Comment: First of all, find that a hidden field with `redirect` name will be setting on the JSP. Check in which cases, it doesn't get populated properly. Meanwhile, if you can modify it's action, you can repopulate it by checking `null`.

Comment: Can you share the JSP's name?

Comment: I'm not quite sure but i think its the "menu.js" file located in:
`portal-web\docroot\html\js\liferay\menu.js`

Comment: Can you attach the snapshot of view? Also, update the liferay version.

Answer (score 0):

As Parkash requested to me, I attached the snapshot of the view.
I have problems only when i try to delete ("Eliminar") the content.

[image: Thats the snapshot Parkash]

Comment: After a lot of test with this issue, i think that maybe be something related to  secure protocol. The environment what is not working is https. In my local (http) the redirect parameter is not null. Any idea?